Book set in/around a space station where the workers get tattoos of equations relevant to their profession
Looking for a title/author of a book I read years ago, when I was in the habit of browsing my library's sci-fi section.  Sadly I only remember a few details:
It's set in/around a space station, no planets (there may be something similar to Niven's Flatlander/Belter social divide going on).  Most of the characters are technical workers of one sort or another, and they all get tattoos of equations relevant to their profession — in the protagonist's case, the Heisenberg uncertainty equation.  She's a young adult whose father disappeared when she was a child; she finds a suit that has weird momentum properties that allow her to "push" against empty space.
Does any of this sound familiar?

In roughly which year did you read this?

Definitely before 2012, probably more like ~2000.

There's a equation tattoo in 2005's "The Woman in Schroedinger's Wave Equation" https://kasmana.people.charleston.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf714, but that doesn't have a space station

No — mine was a full-length novel, not a short story.
